# PHP: Composer uses PHP version older than the used version (on shared hosting)

Tags: php, .htaccess, composer-php

I'm trying to run composer commands from the SSH terminal but I get this

```
Composer detected issues in your platform: Your Composer dependencies require a PHP version ">= 7.3.33". You are running 7.1.33.
```

when I run `php -v` I get `PHP 7.3.33 (cli)`  and when I run `phpinfo()` in Laravel (not the terminal) I get `PHP Version 7.3.33`

In composer.json:

```
"require": {
    "php": "^7.3.33",
```

In .htaccess

```
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php73 .php .php7 .phtml
</IfModule>
```

Why does this happen and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that `.htaccess` only affects the Apache configuration. When accessing the server via SSH the file is completely ignored/useless.

Some providers install multiple versions of PHP, making it available by typing `php7.3`, and the `php` is a simple alias to the current default version. Probably the composer is set up in a way to use a different version of the default (not sure how/why) while your ssh session is using another.

Since your `php -v` is reporting the desired version. I would suggest downloading `composer.phar` and running it locally via `php composer.phar ...` instead of relying on the currently systemwide installed composer.